# start 2 server using npm start

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to start 2 different server using npm start:

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index && http-server ./"
}
```

I wan to start a node app and a http-server to serve Single Page App.

---

Thanks @Lazyexpert for the answer, just use single `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, why not. The start script itself is just a command line command. You can push there whatever works as a command in command line.

Also you might would like to look at npm package [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

Using this package, you start script will look like this:

```
"start": "concurrently \"command1 arg\" \"command2 arg\""
```

Comment: But the script I have, doesn't start the second server.

Comment: @Alvin Oh, you have `&&` this means, that it waits until first command finishes execution. Try to use `&` instead.

Comment: "start": "node index && http-server ./", only start the node app but not the second web app. run http-server ./ works.